# How do I take screenshots of reddit posts using Python and Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, reddit

I want to take a screenshot of the top responses to a post of a selected URL.
The code below is giving me an error in some form of hex / system language that I'm unsure how to troubleshoot.

I am getting this error only when using Chrome. Using Firefox results in better success.

````
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Config

screenshotDir = "Screenshots"

def getPostScreenshots(filePrefix, script):
print("Taking screenshots...")
driver, wait = \__setupDriver(script.url)
script.titleSCFile = \__takeScreenshot(filePrefix, driver, wait)
for commentFrame in script.frames:
commentFrame.screenShotFile = \__takeScreenshot(filePrefix, driver, wait, f"t1_{commentFrame.commentId}")
driver.quit()

def \__takeScreenshot(filePrefix, driver, wait, handle="Post"):
method = By.CLASS_NAME if (handle == "Post") else By.ID
search = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((method, handle)))`your text`
driver.execute_script("window.focus();")

    fileName = f"{screenshotDir}/{filePrefix}-{handle}.png"
    fp = open(fileName, "wb")
    fp.write(search.screenshot_as_png)
    fp.close()
    return fileName

def \__setupDriver(url: str):
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = False
options.enable_mobile = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'Chrome Driver Location', options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
\#driver.set_window_size(width=screenWidth, height=screenHeight)
driver.get(url)

    return driver, wait

Code above produces the following error
GetHandleVerifier \[0x006BDCE3+50899\]
BaseThreadInitThunk \[0x76090099+25\]
RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath \[0x776D7B6E+286\]
RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath \[0x776D7B3E+238\]
```
````